# Magento 2 - automatic product information transfer (rest, soap?)

Tags: rest, soap, magento2

I have multiple Magento 2 websites and i do not want to use CSV or XML to update my product details. I would like to develop a feed or other connection to automatically update the product information from the main (parent) website to the other (child) websites.

Which technology would be the best to set this up? Rest? I am looking for some suggestions to point me in the right direction.